# Decreasing tail integrals for nonnegative random variable $X$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable with density function $f(x)$, distribution function $F(x)$, survival function $S(x)=1-F(x)$ and finite first and second moments. Let also
$$\ell(x):=\frac{1}{xS(x)}\int_{x}^{+\infty}S(u)du,\quad\quad \mu(x):=\frac{1}{S(e^x)}\int_{e^x}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{u}S(u)du$$

I want to show or find a counterexample that: $\mu(x)$ is decreasing in $x>-\infty$ if and only if $\ell(x)$ is decreasing in $x>0$.

Since $\frac1u=\ln{(u)}'$, I am trying to use a variable transformation, $t\to \ln{u}$ in $\mu(x)$. This is similar to considering the variable transformation $X\to \ln{(X)}$. However, from the result, I cannot get the equivalence. So, I am currently thinking of constructing a counterexample, possibly using the Pareto distribution with $x_m=1$ and $\alpha>1$ (using the Wikipedia notation) which has $S(x)=x^{-a}$, but again, I cannot get a counterexample.

In fact, I expect the answer to be no (so, I am more inclined to look for a counterexample). The reason is that $\ell(x)$ is constant for the Pareto distribution. However, $\mu(x)$ would be constant for the exponential distribution, where *exponential = $\ln{}$(Pareto)*, if there was not the $1/u$ term inside the integral. On the other hand, the $1/u$ is also decreasing, so maybe it is possible to show only the one direction and find a counterexample for the other direction.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reason? If there is something wrong with the question, 
I would be glad to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvoter has in mind, and I'm not analytically-inclined enough to comment on the content of the question but the question reads more like a (well-written) Math Stack Exchange question than like a MathOverflow question. If you could give some more context for why you are interested in this question -- why one might expect the answer to be "yes" (or "no"), how it ties in to known results in the literature, etc. -- it might appeal a bit more to the community here.

Comment: It's also relevant to discuss what approaches you've tried, but we're not here to police your "effort" specifically, like a teacher in office hours who needs a window into what you know and what you don't know, and what your thought process is. When professional mathematicians talk to each other, this sort of information is often more efficiently signalled by giving an indication of what relevant papers you've read. The upshot is: I'd suggest deleting the word "effort" which you have in bold (but keep the text following it in some form).

Comment: @TimCampion Ok, thank you, noted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This iff statement is false. Indeed, this iff statement can be restated as follows:

> If
> $$\ell(x):=\frac1{xS(x)}\int_x^\infty S(u)\,du\quad\text{and}\quad 
> m(x):=\frac1{S(x)}\int_x^\infty\frac{S(u)}{u}\,du,$$
> then $\ell$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ iff $m$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.

To show that the highlighted statement is false,
let
$$a:=\frac{757}{256},\ b:=-1,\ c:=\frac{729}{8192}$$
and then let
$$\tilde S(x):=x (a + b x + c x^2) e^{-x}$$
for $x\ge6$, with $\tilde S(x):=S(6)$ for $x\in[0,6)$, and then let
$$S(x):=\tilde S(x)/\tilde S(0).$$

Then $S$ is a positive nonincreasing to $0$ function on $[0,\infty)$ with $S(0)=1$, so that $S$ is a survival function. Moreover, on $(0,6]$ the function $S$ is constant and hence $\ell$ is obviously decreasing. Also, $\ell'<0$ on $[6,\infty)$. So, $\ell$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. However, $m'(6)=\frac{17141}{2597784}>0$, and hence the function $m$ is not decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. $\quad\Box$

---

Here is an image of the Mathematica notebook with the corresponding calculations:

[image]

Comment: Dear @Iosif, thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to convert $S(x)$ to a valid survival function or is this not a problem? Currently, I cannot get $S(x)$ to start with $S(x_0) =0$ for some $x_0\ge0$. Also, in the initial iff statement, I had $x\ge0$ in mind for both $\ell(x)$ and $\mu(x)$. Does the counterexample hinge on strengthening the statement to hold for all $x>-\infty$ for the $\mu$ function? (hints for both questions would be great). Thank you again so much!

Comment: @JimmyR. : (i) Yes, it is very easy to convert $S$ to a survival function, and this is now done. (ii) Having $x\ge0$ both for $\ell$ and $\mu$ does not make much sense to me, because then you consider $S(u)$ with $u>0$ for $\ell(x)$, and $S(u)$ with $u>1$ for $\mu(x)$. So, knowing $\mu(x)$ for all $x\ge0$, you would have almost no control over the values of $S(u)$ with $u\in(0,1)$ and hence little control over the values of $\ell(x)$ with $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Anyhow, the crucial value $6$ in the answer for the argument of $m$ corresponds to the value $\ln6>0$ for the argument of $\mu$. So, even if you only consider $x\ge0$ for $\mu(x)$ (which you should have done explicitly), the counterexample in this answer remains valid.

Comment: Thank you again so much for your comments. Actually, I should have explained that I want to consider $\mu(x)$ also for $x\ge0$. But, I tested your example, and it works. When I plot it, $\mu(x)$ is decreasing except for a very small interval after $x=6$. I also simplified the constants a bit and I will play around to get a different example (with larger interval in which $\mu(x)$ increases) but your help was incredible. And coming up with such an example is not trivial at all. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JimmyR. : Thank you for your appreciation. It took indeed some effort to find this example.